# How to update database using LINQ EF in MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I tried this one. I din't encounter error and i tried to put breakpoint to trace and it works but in the database it din't update... what is the problem?

```
SanipexContext db = new SanipexContext();
public ActionResult ProductUpdate()
{
var exist = from e in db.SGRDetails
            where e.SGRnumber == sgr && e.product == prodname
            select e;
foreach (var s in exist)
{
    s.percentage = 20;
}
db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to attach the object with the db context to make it effect in the database :

```
foreach (var item in exist)
{
  s.percentage = 20;
  db.Context.SGRDetails.Attach(item )
  DbEntityEntry<SGRDetail> entry = db.Entry(item);
  entry.Property(e => e.percentage).IsModified = true;
}

  db.SaveChanges();
```